# Can't get JQuery to remove a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting started with JQuery by trying to get a hidden message to show up.
However when I load it, the message is still hidden. 
The message has two classes "error" and "hidden", I want to remove the class "hidden" with javascript/JQuery.

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <span class="error hidden" id="error">This field is required.</span>

    <script>
        $("error").removeClass("hidden");
    </script>
</body>
```

My css

```
.hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: missing `.` in class selector `$(".error").removeClass("hidden");`

Comment: Check your browser's console and make sure you are not getting `TypeError: $ is undefined` error, if yes, add [JQuery Library](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js)

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, the id of the element is supposed to be "error" as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("error")` will not work because `error` is not a valid selector. You need to use a valid CSS id selector to select the element:

```
$("#error").removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, the id of the element is supposed to be "error"

Comment: @SJacobs it'll work either way - `.error` or `#error`, in this case

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Will select this as answer when possible.